# register_setting and AJAX?

Tags: ajax, theme-options, customization

Please pardon me if this question is totally unrelated in itself, but I'll do my best to point out the issue I am having and what I would like to achieve.

**Scenario:** I have a custom theme option's panel, that uses custom-made tabs.
**Goal:** Whenever the user saves the panel's options, the page and the panel's tabs should stay just like they are (i.e. no reloading and no taking-the-user-back to initial tab). I am almost completely certain that this is AJAX-related, thus the title.

This is the PHP code of my panel: http://pastie.org/3102112

This is the JS that makes the tabs works (for the sake of this example, as the tabs themselves work flawlessly):

```
$('div#options_tabs div.block').hide();
$('ul.options_tabs li:first').addClass('active').show();
$('div#options_tabs div.block:first').show();

$('ul.options_tabs li').click(function() {

    $('ul.options_tabs li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('div#options_tabs div.block').fadeOut(100);

    var activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

And finally, my attempt at AJAXing the tabs and the way my panel is saved (note that I am really clueless as to what should be placed within the AJAX action; and I also feel I might be completely off-track, as my panel uses the WordPress built-in register_settings method):

```
(function ($) {

inlineEditOption = {
    init: function () {
        $('.save-options', '#the-theme-options').live('click', function () {
            inlineEditOption.save_options(this);
            return false;
        });
    },

    save_options: function (e) {
      var d = {
        action: "options.php"
      };
      b = $(':input').serialize();
      d = b + "&" + $.param(d);
      $.post(ajaxurl, d, function (r) {
        if (r != -1) {
          $('.ajax-message').ajaxMessage('<div class="message"><span>&nbsp;</span>Theme Options were saved</div>');
        } else {
          $('.ajax-message').ajaxMessage('<div class="message warning"><span>&nbsp;</span>Theme Options could not be saved</div>');
        }
      });
      return false;
    }

}
});
```

Anyhow, I hope I was clear enough; if I forgot something please let me know!
Thank you all in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress already provides a very nice API for admin / option page tabs.  No need to reinvent the wheel on that one.

Your Ajax action is "options.php" You need an action that's linked to a PHP function that gets included by `add_action( 'wp_ajax_YOUR-ACTION-NAME*', 'your_php_function');`

<sup>* `YOUR-ACTION-NAME` is the action you defined when localizing the script</sup>

Take a look at Chip Bennet's very detailed tutorial on the [Settings API](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/).  It covers just about everything including tabs.

There is also a lot of great information here-> [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) on WordPress Ajax.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks a ton - I have no idea how I hadn't seen that tutorial. However, in my case I cannot turn all my panel back and start with the tutorial from scratch. The code I am showing above is a tiny excerpt of a highly customized panel. Thus, I would simply like to adapt my current tabular-system to one that support AJAX. Is that possible?